# How do I plot a graph in R, with the first values in one colour and the next values in another colour?

Tags: r, plot, colors, data-visualization

I've been trying this out but I cannot find a solution. The best I can do is plotting the first 15846 values in 1 colour and then using the `lines()` function to add the remaining 841 points. But these then appear at the start of the graph and does not continue from the 15846th datapoint.

```
str(as.numeric(sigma.in.fr))
 num [1:15846] 0.000408 0.000242 0.000536 0.000274 0.000476 ...

str(as.numeric(sigma.out.fr))
 num [1:841] 0.002558 0.000428 0.000255 0.000549 0.00028 ...

plot(as.numeric(sigma.in.fr),type="l",col=c("tomato4"))
lines(as.numeric(sigma.out.fr), type="l",col="tomato1")
```

This returns the plot below:

[image: this plot]]

Comment: Please post the output of `str(x)` where `x` is the name of your data set. And the code you have tried. Post both **in the question**, please.

Comment: I've included that. I'm kind of new to the more complex R plots, so I'm not too sure

Answer (score 3):

Lets make some dummy data to demonstrate:

```
sigma.ins.fr = sin((1:800)/20) + rnorm(800)
sigma.outs.fr = sin((801:1000)/20) + rnorm(200)
```

Now, put all the data together into a single sequence

```
sigma.all = c(sigma.ins.fr, sigma.outs.fr)
```

And create an x vector which simply counts along the data.  We'll need this in the `segments` call below.

```
x = seq_along(sigma.all)
```

Now create a vector of colors for the trace.  It is the same length as the full data, with a color for each segment.

```
cols = c(rep("tomato4", length(sigma.ins.fr)), rep("blue", length(sigma.outs.fr)))
```

Now create a blank canvass on which to draw the data.

```
plot(sigma.all, type="l", col=NA)
```

At last, we can plot the data.  Unfortunately, `lines` does not allow for a separate color in different segments.  So instead we can use `segments`

```
segments(head(x,-1), head(sigma.all,-1), x[-1], sigma.all[-1], type="l", col=cols)
```

[image]

Or, if you really prefer to use two separate traces uning `lines`, then we can achieve this by adding the x coordinates to each call:

```
plot(sigma.all, type="l", col=NA)
lines(seq_along(sigma.ins.fr), sigma.ins.fr, col=c("tomato4"))
lines(seq_along(sigma.outs.fr) + length(sigma.ins.fr), sigma.outs.fr, col="tomato1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a reproducible example. Using the packages `ggplot2` and `dplyr` you can do something like:

```
df <- tibble(x = seq(1,1000, 1), y = seq(1, 500.5, 0.5))


ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df %>% filter(x < 800),
            aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", size =2) +
  geom_line(data = df %>% filter(x >= 800), 
            aes(x = x, y = y),
            color = "black", size = 2)
```

[image]

Note that I put the cut off at 800 (as I only created 1000 points), but you can easily change that.

So what I do is putting the data in geom_line, as you can also use this if you have different dataframes (with overlapping x and y) you want to plot in the same graph. However, I do filter the data at different points, so that different lines are drawn by the geom_line.

Comment: My dataframe is in numeric form and I don't have x and y values, only one column to be plotted but I want 1st:1000th rows in one colour and the next 1001th:1200th in another colour.

Comment: @user521623 it doesn't matter what you want to plot, you can do this trick with all geom_ functions. Just google a bit and you will find enough examples. However, apparently you want a costum made answer for your question so that you do not have to change anything, which is impossible without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks Annet. I'll look for ggplot graphs